# Rothschild purchased Israel excluding the temple mount

Tags: halacha, responsa

I was told that Rothschild wanted to purchase the temple mount when he was purchasing land in Israel, but did not because the Rabbis were against it

What were the reasons the Rabbis were against it?
Are there responsa regarding this (which I can read)?

(I only found was https://socioecohistory.wordpress.com/2015/09/30/1829-newspaper-rothschilds-have-purchased-jerusalem/ and

> Rabbi Zvi Hirsh Kalisher, a leading figure in this effort, turned in writing to the greatest Jewish philanthropist of the age - Baron Asher Anshil Rothschild, who commanded the respect of all the world's royalty. R. Kalisher suggested that he offer to purchase the entire land of Israel at a high price from Ibrahim Pasha, King of Egypt, who ruled over the Holy Land at the time. The land itself was barren and desolate. R. Kalisher also suggested an alternative possibility, in the event that the first one should be rejected - to request the minimal purchase of Jerusalem and the Temple Mount. The Rabbi explains at great length, how the renewal of the Temple service will lead to the mass immigration of the Jewish people from the lands of their oppression, resulting eventually in the settlement of the entire land of Israel

From http://www.templeinstitute.org/build.htm

Answer (score 4):

*"What were the reasons the Rabbis were against it?"*

According to the [Hebrew Wikipedia article](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99#.D7.9E.D7.A2.D7.9E.D7.93.D7.95_.D7.94.D7.9E.D7.A9.D7.A4.D7.98.D7.99_.D7.95.D7.94.D7.9E.D7.93.D7.99.D7.A0.D7.99), the Rabbis were worried about the Arabs violent reaction to such a purchase. 
  <sup>The English Wikipedia article has no reference to this.</sup>

> ב-1887 ניסה הברון אדמונד דה רוטשילד לרכוש את הכותל בעת ביקורו בארץ ישראל. **ליוזמה זו התנגדו רבני ירושלים, מחשש לתגובה קשה של הערבים המוסלמים בעיר**‏

*"Are there responsa regarding this (which I can read)?"*

None that I could find, except for Rav Tzi Hirsch Kaslisher who discusses the concept in his Sefer דרישת ציון and sent a letter to Baron ([Source](https://www.temple.org.il/single-post/2016/12/13/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA)).

You can read about it online at HebrewBooks [starting at page 69](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31793&st=%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%91&pgnum=68&hilite=) - where he first discusses the concept of buying and then brings his correspondence with various Rabbis on the subject.

BTW: He also tried purchasing the houses adjacent to the Kotel in order to enlarge the area. ([Source](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D#.D7.94.D7.A0.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.95.D7.9F_.D7.9C.D7.A8.D7.9B.D7.99.D7.A9.D7.AA_.D7.94.D7.A9.D7.9B.D7.95.D7.A0.D7.94_.D7.91.D7.99.D7.93.D7.99_.D7.94.D7.91.D7.A8.D7.95.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.95.D7.98.D7.A9.D7.99.D7.9C.D7.93),  [Source](http://lib.cet.ac.il/pages/item.asp?item=8683) that he tried buying the Kotel)